# Changing variant image in Shopify

Tags: shopify

I have a product on a Shopify hosted website that has several colors.  I am trying to change the code so that all of the thumbnails are hidden, except for the color that is selected.  The code is shown below, and works, except that the main image does not change when the color selected is changed.  Any suggestions?
Here's the live page: https://www.palmettowoodshop.com/collections/featured/products/docking-station-cherry?variant=33412918350

```js
{% assign option_name = 'Color' %}

{% if product.options contains option_name %}

<script>
// Grabbing product thumbnails
// Covers: Editions, Launchpad Star, Lookbook, Kickstand, Startup, Simple, Radiance, Minimal, Supply, New Standard and many more.
var thumbnails = jQuery('img[src*="/products/"]') /* All product images */
  .not('#related-products img')                   /* Except related products, thumbnails not clickable */
  .not('a[href^="/collections/"] img')            /* Except related products */
  .not('a[href^="/products/"] img')               /* Except mini-cart products */
  .not('header img')                              /* Except mini-cart products, thumbnails not clickable */
  .not('#drawer img')                             /* Except mini-cart products, thumbnails not clickable, in Simple theme. */
  .not(':first');                                 /* Except first one, i.e the main image */
  
var optionSelect; 
{% assign option_index = 0 %}  
{% for option in product.options %}
  {% if option == option_name %}
    {% assign option_index = forloop.index0 %}  
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
  
{% if product.options.size == 1 %}
  optionSelect = '.single-option-selector';
{% else %}
  optionSelect = 'label:contains({{ option_name }}) + .single-option-selector';   
{% endif %}
  
jQuery('form[action="/cart/add"]').on('change', optionSelect, function() {
  var optionValue = $(this).val();
  thumbnails.each(function() {
    var wrapper = $(this);
    while ( wrapper.parent().children().length === 1 ) {
      wrapper = wrapper.parent();
    }
    if ( jQuery(this).attr('alt') === optionValue ) {
      wrapper.show();
    }
    else {
      wrapper.hide();
    }
  });
});    
</script>

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, change `.not(':first');` to `.not('.feature-row__image')` or whatever the class name of your featured image.